# How do i show a directory in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operating-system, c++14

I want to see what directory l'm in, like this picture of a terminal: [image: like this picture]

How do I do this in c++?

Comment: Did you intentionally tag it C++11/C++14? Because `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path` is C++17.

Comment: `cwd()` Will tell you the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your C++ taste, with C++17 you can use the [std::filesystem::current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) as shown in example.
(Make sure to compile with `-std=c++17` and link `-lstdc++fs` as some compilers need it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

Or an OS-dependent [getcwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man2/getcwd.2.html) which will work with pre-c++17.

Comment: but where will it show that then and in what folder/file should I put it if I used the chromium OS?

Comment: no, I want to know where I should put the code to always show it and and on what position it will be (left top, right top, middle, left bottom and etc).

Comment: You likely need some type of GUI framework for that. Also the current directory does not really make a lot of sense because it would only show the current directory of the application that is printing the result. This result would not change unless you changed it in the application that was the display. The display would have nothing to do with any other application on your system.

Comment: The reason I want this is so the admin at my old school can test the beta and see where the files are located and edit if he needs to. I'm making an OS for his school computers.